# Derivative of product involving cosine transform in chain rule becomes antitransform

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-transform, chain-rule

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.05946) in section 4 they define

$$
\bf{h_1} = \bf{x_i} \bf{A}\mbox{; } h_2=h_1C\mbox{; } h_3 = h_2 D\mbox{; } y_i = h_3 C^{-1}
$$

where $\bf{A} = diag(\bf{a})$ and $\bf{D} = diag(\bf{d})$. Cosine transform is defined such that $\bf{C}^{-1} = \bf{C}'$.

Then they apply the chain rule for derivatives and write:

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \bf{d}} = \frac{\partial \bf{y_i}}{\partial \bf{d}} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \bf{y_i}} = \frac{\partial \bf{h_2} \bf{D}}{\partial \bf{d}}\frac{\partial \bf{h_3}\bf{C}^{-1}}{\partial \bf{h_3}}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \bf{y_i}} = diag(\bf{h_2})\bf{C} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \bf{y_i}}
$$

and also

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \bf{a}} = \frac{\partial \bf{x_i} \bf{A}}{\partial \bf{a}}\frac{\partial \bf{h_1C}}{\partial \bf{h_1}}\frac{\partial\bf{ h_2 D}}{\partial \bf{h_2}}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \bf{h_3}} = \bf{x_i} \odot \bf{C}^{-1}\bf{d} \odot\bf{C}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \bf{y_i}}
$$

What I don't understand is how $\frac{\partial \bf{h_3}\bf{C}^{-1}}{\partial \bf{h_3}} = \bf{C}$ and $\frac{\partial \bf{h_1C}}{\partial \bf{h_1}} = \bf{C}^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

It' s a problem of convention, they use denominator convention, therefore the result is the transpose of what I'd have said. Being their definition of discrete cosine transform orthogonal, $C^{-1} = C^T$ and $(C^T)^T = C$.